# How to replace a word using "vi editor"?

Tags: vi

I have here a sample text file called employees.txt. It contains the name, streets and cities of the employees.

My question is: How can I replace all city instances of "Victoria" with "City of Victoria". Only the city is affected, not places like Victoria Drive or people like Ashley Victoria?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: For this you need to come up with a situations where all Victoria are distinguishable from all other "other word+Victoria+other word". Otherwise this will be impossible. Alternative: replace all and then replace all those that have an extra word? Is that an option? Basically what I am asking.... are those 2 the exception or is there more you want to skip?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell vim to ask for confirmation:

```
:%s/Victoria/City\sof\sVictoria/gc
```

- the %s replaces, the g does it globally, the c asks for confirumatiom
- the \s is for a space.

That might be the quickest but does involve some manual work.

If those are the only 2 this would work too:

```
:%s/Victoria/City\sof\sVictoria/g
:%s/City\sof\sVictoria\sDrive/City\sof\sVictoria/g
:%s/Ashley\sCity\sof\sVictoria/Ashley\sVictoria/g
```

but if there are more of these this can become a long list. And do make a backup before you do this ;)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about regular expression [lookaround assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

At least in `vim` (**v**i **im**proved) , you can use `\@!` for negative lookahead and `\@<!` for negative lookbehind. So for example to match `Victoria` that is **not** preceded by `Ashley`  (Ashley-space):

```
\(Ashley \)\@<!Victoria
```

whereas to match `Victoria` that is **not** followed by  `Drive` (space-Drive):

```
Victoria\( Drive\)\@!
```

Putting these together:

```
 :s/\(Ashley \)\@<!Victoria\( Drive\)\@!/City of &/g
```

where `&` on the RHS backsubstitutes the matching `Victoria`. Generalizing to any capitalized "words" before and after `Victoria`:

```
:s/\([[:upper:]][[:alpha:]-]* \)\@<!Victoria\( [[:upper:]][[:alpha:]-]*\)\@!/City of &/g
```

See also:

- [Is lookaround possible in vim's regex system?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3036/is-lookaround-possible-in-vims-regex-system)
- [Is there a way to do negative lookahead in vim regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148467/is-there-a-way-to-do-negative-lookahead-in-vim-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Another way: (manual)

Search for `Victoria`:

> /Victoria

If it matches your requirements, enter insert mode (`i`) then type `City of`

Then in command mode go to next find (`n`), and if it matches strike the point (`.`) it will insert `City of`  again, if it does not match go to next find and so on so forth ....